# Can a zombie dragon make a full attack?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, undead, dragons, zombies

Can a zombie dragon (Draconomicon) full attack, seeing as the option exists in their combat unlike the normal zombie template.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The zombie dragon is not the result of applying the zombie template to any dragon; it is a wholly independent creature. So nothing about the zombie template rules applies to the zombie dragon unless it explicitly says so.

However, the zombie dragon *does* say that it shares the zombie’s slow trait. That contradicts the stat block (which lists a full-attack), but per the errata rules, text trumps table, so zombie dragons cannot full-attack.

Comment: Part of the zombie template says "Slow (Ex): Like zombies, zombie dragons have poor reflexes and can perform only a single standard action or move action each round.". This is a contradiction of the options of the stat block.

Comment: @Simon Ah, my fault for not double-checking. In that case, the text trumps the stat block, so yeah, the zombie dragon cannot full-attack.

Comment: Can you site that errata (text/table) reference?  I've heard it referenced before but not sited.